# Group Posts by Category in Monthly Archive

Tags: wordpress, archive

I am trying to group the posts by Category in a Monthly archive but don't know how to achieve that.

Can someone here help me please.

Regards

---

This is the php code I am using in archive.php

```
<?php
        $terms = get_terms("publicationcat");
        $count = count($terms);
        if ( $count > 0 ){
            foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
                echo "<div class=\"publication-area\">";
                echo '<h3 class="term-heading">' . $term->name . '</h3>';
                echo "<div class=\"publication-txt\">";
                echo "<ul>";
                while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
                echo "<li><a target=\"_blank\" href=\"" . wp_get_attachment_url(get_post_meta($post->ID, 'document_file_id', true)) . "\">".$post->post_title."</a></li>";
                endwhile; 
                echo "</ul>";
                echo "</div>";
                echo "</div>";
            }
        }
        ?>
```

The only problem is that its displaying same post titles for all the terms..

Comment: Hey Himanshu, what function are you using at the moment to output the archive?

Comment: Hi Barry,

I just edited the question and pasted the php code..

Answer (score 0):

When you get to looping through the post in each category, you are not finding only the posts related to that category, and are instead looping through EVERY post. The below (untested, so comment if you get errors) should sort your problem.

Please note however that you may still get some repetition, if a post is assigned to more than one category.

Check each post to ensure it is in the desired category. Good point - only one query. Bad point - loops through all posts for every cat.

```
<?php
$terms = get_terms('publicationcat');

if(!empty($terms)) : foreach($terms as $term) :
?>
        <div class="publication-area">

            <?php sprintf('<h3 class="term-heading">%1$s</h3>', $term->name); ?>
            <div class="publication-txt">

                <?php if($my_query->have_posts()) : ?>

                    <ul>

                    <?php if(in_category($term->slug)) : ?>

                    <?php while($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>

                            <?php $link = wp_get_attachment_url(get_post_meta($post->ID, 'document_file_id', true)); ?>
                            <li><a target="_blank" href="<?php echo ($link !== '') ? $link : ''; ?>">
                                <?php the_title(); ?>
                            </a></li>

                        <?php endwhile; ?>

                    <?php endif; ?>

                    </ul>

                <?php endif; ?>

            </div>

        </div>
<?php
    endforeach;
endif;
?>
```

Re-query the posts and output all that are grabbed. Good point - only pulls only the posts required for the category being looped. Bad point - lots of queries, so many queries could slow your site down.

```
<?php
$terms = get_terms('publicationcat');

if(!empty($terms)) : foreach($terms as $term) :
?>
        <div class="publication-area">

            <?php sprintf('<h3 class="term-heading">%1$s</h3>', $term->name); ?>
            <div class="publication-txt">

                <?php
                $args = array(
                    'cat' => $term->term_id
                );
                $my_query = new WP_Query($args);
                ?>
                <ul>
                    <?php if($my_query->have_posts()) : while($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>

                            <?php $link = wp_get_attachment_url(get_post_meta($post->ID, 'document_file_id', true)); ?>
                            <li><a target="_blank" href="<?php echo ($link !== '') ? $link : ''; ?>">
                                <?php the_title(); ?>
                            </a></li>

                        <?php endwhile; ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>

                </ul>

            </div>

        </div>
<?php
    endforeach;
endif;
?>
```

Comment: Hello David,
I just tried your code but its not working and not displaying anything.
Also I am using the code for displaying date archives so would it be suitable to run a custom query ?

Comment: Try now. Have corrected one typo and tested this, working fine on my site. This code should be fine for your archive also, you just need to amend the query as you require for your date range.

Comment: Ok, so I've added another method of doing this that is probably more suitable for an archive page (the first of the two examples). Over all, it's probably less efficient, but when dealing with dates, it easier and quicker because you don't have to manually construct queries.

Comment: Can you please repost a query I can use in archive page ?